# Bounded norm gradiënt implies bounded norm function itself?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

So I work in the space $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ with $d \geq 1$. $\Omega$ is sufficiently bounded domain. We've got a function $f$ on $\Omega$. Now follows my question.
If $\left\|\nabla f \right\|^2 \leq C$ (thus $f\in H^1(\Omega)$), can we conclude then that $\left\|f \right\|^2 \leq C'$ (thus $f \in L_2(\Omega)$)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The space of functions for which $\|\nabla f\|_2$ is bounded is oftem called a *homogeneous* Sobolev space, and is often denoted by $\dot H^1(\Omega)$.  This generalizes to $\dot W^{p,n}$, where only $\|\nabla^n f\|_p$ is computed.  The homogeneity refers to the fact that $\|f(\lambda\cdot)\| = \lambda^\alpha \|f\|$.

Answer (score 2):

No. The constant function is the counter-example.

Answer (score 1):

No. The functions $f_n = f + n$ all have the same gradients, but $ \|f_n\|^2 \nearrow + \infty$.

The best you can say is the following: let $\bar{f} = \frac{1}{|\Omega|} \int_\Omega f ~\mathrm{d}x$ be the average of $f$ on $\Omega$. Then

$$ \|\nabla f\|^2 \leq C \implies \| f - \bar{f}\|^2 \leq C' $$

for some $C'$ depending on $\Omega$ and $C$. This is the content of [Poincare's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_inequality).

(Alternatively, instead of subtracting out the average, you can restrict to working with functions vanishing on the boundary $\partial\Omega$: the implication you want is true if you consider functions $f$ in $C^\infty_0(\Omega)$, for example. Then you can argue by density for functions $f\in H^1_0(\Omega)$. See, for example, Evans' PDE text book.)

Comment: And the other side, is that correct? So if the function itself is bounded, can we conclude that the gradient of that function is bounded?

Comment: No. Reverse Poincare is usually false, when no other conditions are given. Let $f$ be any function of compact support, you can rescale $f$ in a way to keep the $L^2$ norm constant by make the $\dot{H}^1$ norm as big as you want.

Comment: http://www.ce.berkeley.edu/~sanjay/me180ce133/err_est.pdf

Comment: What is the difference with this document on the second page between the 5th en 6th equation?

Comment: Nothing in what you quoted has anything to do about the type of estimate you are asking about. Do you really mean between the 5th and 6th equation? Note that $f'$ is just a shorthand notation for $\nabla f$.

Comment: They say that $H_1 \subset L_2$

Comment: @Silke: be careful with homogeneous and inhomogeneous versions of Sobolev spaces. And yes, $H^1 \subseteq L^2$, since $H^1$ is the set of functions $f$ such that $\|f\|_{L^2} + \|\nabla f\|_{L^2}$ is finite, and so in particular $\|f\|_{L^2}$ must be finite also. See also Stephen's comment on your original post.